# C# WPF onclick change location of listbox and textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a total beginner in this field so I need some help. 
In my application I have to different buttons which has to change to position or location of some elements on click. 
I have one Textbox and one ListBox with 4 Listboxitems and on button click their position has to change.
Can you please tell me how to implement this in code.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you search for any guides / tutorials? I think this information should be fairly easy to find.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your research assistant.  If you show your work and explain what you have tried we can help with problems but we can't tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF you normally use the MVVM pattern. If you haven't heard of it, there is a good explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). So basically, you listbox is just a presentation of an underlying list of data items. You don't change the presentation listboxitems, but instead change the items in the underlying collection and let the WPF UI handle the resulting update of the presentation layer.

You button should activate a command that switches the data in the viewmodel (or even in the model, depending on your needs). For an introduction to commands, you might find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) interesting.